# Shibboleth Could not locate Java.exe Please check the value for JAVA_HOME

Tags: windows, java, shibboleth

I am trying to install Shibboleth for development on my local copy of windows 10.

I am on the first step and stuck. After downloading the shibboleth identity provider I am not able to install as I get the following error:
`Shibboleth Could not locate Java.exe. Please check the value for JAVA_HOME` I have installed the latest JRE and linked to it in the the ENV variables properly but the installer seems to not like the path. Let6 me know if any other info is needed. Thanks in advance!

See images attached for details.
This is where the var is defined under:

My Computer->RightClick->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environmental Variables->System Variables

[image: The env var]

Here is proof that is is set up:
[image: the value]

Here is the java.exe file:
[image: The java.exe]

Comment: Please leave a comment if you are going to vote !!!!

Comment: Downvotes without comment can be assumed to be for one of the reasons listed in the downvote arrow hover text.

Answer (score 4):

> I have installed the latest JRE and linked to it in the the ENV
>   variables properly

Actually, it doesn't look like you've done that properly.

The `JAVA_HOME` environment variable should not point to the java binary itself, but rather to the grandparent folder of the binary.

In your case, it should point to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\`.

Comment: Just encountered this. Properly setting the JAVA_HOME variable to parent directory of the jre_version worked for me too. Thanks.